# How to connect database to laravel 5.5 in Google app engine

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I created one Google Cloud SQL instance and hosted a laravel project on Google App Engine. But when I access my laravel project it shows error database connection.

Both are on same project, SQL and laravel.

Note: I enabled Google Cloud SQL API service.

Comment: There is a community Tutorial on how to use Laravel with the Flexible Runtime Environment for PHP. This link tells you how to set up the DB connection:  https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible#set-up-database-sessions. Tell me if it works please

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your laravel project to use the google cloud sql. The database configuration for your application is located at `config/database.php`

You have to modify that file with credentials you set up for your google cloud sql. Instructions about how to set up credentials is here:

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/how-to/migrate-database-cloud-sql/

Comment: @SagarShinde maybe you can post your configuration settings